# Problem with child product in Magento 2.4.6 Cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I have a problem with the cart section. When I add multiple times the same child product from a configurable product, in the cart it's shows as a different products not as the same with more qtys. Also in DB it's different records not the same records with more qtys.

I'm trying to figure out what happens. Can anyone helps me?

Thanks!

Add 2 times the same child product in the cart. Show one time the product with qtys 2. Now it's shows 2 times the same product and this is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some custom code or a third part module is that modifying Magento to do this, specifically

```
Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item::representProduct
```

You could try and search the codebase for plugins / preferences that modify this as it's often modified to achieve exactly this behaviour.